# Group by each increasing sequence in data frame

Tags: r, grouping, sequence

If I have a data frame with a column of monotonically increasing values such as:

```
x
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
```

How do I add a column to group each increasing sequence that results in:

```
x   y
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
1   3
2   3
3   3
4   3
5   3
6   3
1   4
2   4
```

I can only think of using a loop which will be slow.

Comment: Does each new sequence start at 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may choose `cumsum` function to do it.

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,4,5,1,2)
> cumsum(x==1)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `diff` and compute the cumulative sum:

```
df$y <- c(1, cumsum(diff(df$x) < 0 ) + 1)

> df
   x y
1  1 1
2  2 1
3  3 1
4  4 1
5  1 2
6  2 2
7  3 2
8  1 3
9  2 3
10 3 3
11 4 3
12 5 3
13 6 3
14 1 4
15 2 4
```